# module export in ts file is not a module error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a config.ts and I do

```
module.exports = { something: 123 }
```

when I import like import { something } from './config.ts' I got error of `config.ts' is not a module`, what's the issue? my typescript is configured rightly and it's working in other places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `import { something } from './config.ts'`, you're using JavaScript modules, but your code in `config.ts` is using CommonJS modules. Some bundlers and such may let you mix them, but it's best not to.

To make `config.ts` a JavaScript module compatible with that `import` declaration (which expects a named export called `something`), change it to:

```
export const something = 123;
```

---

Or, of course, to use `config.ts` via CommonJS, your code using it would be:

```
const { something } = require("./config.ts");
```

...but given the error you're getting, I think your project is set up to use JavaScript modules (`import`/`export`), which here in almost 2021 is probably best (now that we have [dynamic import](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import) to handle the cases where static modules don't quite do the job).

Comment: (FWIW, I go into JavaScript modules, including dynamic import and a bit about the contrast with CommonJS, in Chapter 13 of my new[ish] book, *JavaScript: The New Toys* about the new features in ES2015-ES2020 [plus a bit]. Links in my profile if you're interested.)

Comment: I'm able to import package using `import moment from 'moment'`, I don't have to use require as I use typescript I guess? or I should use another type of exports?

Comment: @NadielyJade - Right, you don't need to use `require`. You're using JavaScript modules. What you need to do is make `config.ts` a JavaScript module, as shown above. (No, there's no need to use a different type of module. You *could*, but IMHO there's no good reason to now that ESM [JavaScript module syntax] is so well supported in TypeScript and across various other tools.)